Tracking : Disable marker when it reaches a drawn area
I have video footage taken from a car which I need to track but the car's shadow is always messing up my tracking :

I could increase the correlation setting but it would remove other tracks I may need so I'd prefer to find a way to disable tracks once they reach a drawn area (in my case the car's shadow).
Grease pencil can be used to detect features inside or outside an area. However, once you start tracking, the area is no longer taken into account.
Is there still some way to do it ?
